# SQL Conditional JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have three tables 'Employees', 'Departments' and 'EmployeesInDepartments'
The 'Employees' tables references the 'Departments' table (Each employee must have a DepartmentId). However, an employee can exist in multiple departments by adding entries (EmployeeId and DepartmentId) to 'EmployeeInDepartments' table.

I currently have the following stored procedure to retrieve employees by departmentId:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.CollectEmployeesByDepartmentId
    (
    @DepartmentId int,
    @IsDeleted bit
    )
AS
BEGIN
        SELECT   Employees.*
        FROM      Employees 
        WHERE   ((Employees.IsDeleted = @IsDeleted )
            AND ((Employees.DepartmentId = @DepartmentId)
                OR (Employees.EmployeeId IN (SELECT EmployeesInDepartments.EmployeeId
                                        FROM EmployeesInDepartments 
                                        WHERE (EmployeesInDepartments.DepartmentId = @DepartmentId)
                                        )
                    )
                )
        )   
END
```

How can I optimize this stored procedure and possibly use JOINS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   SELECT E.*
   FROM Employees E
      Left Join EmployeesInDepartments EID ON E.EmployeeId = EID.EmployeeId
         And E.DepartmentId <> @DepartmentId 

   WHERE E.IsDeleted = @IsDeleted
      And
      (  
         E.DepartmentId = @DepartmentId 
         Or (EID.DepartmentId = @DepartmentId)
      )
```

Edit to include IsDeleted logic.
I do agree with some of the other answers, your design should probably be changed. But this query should do it. If you have duplicates in EmployeesInDepartments, you can change that to a Select Distinct.

Comment: Although this does not have many votes, this is the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

My first recommendation to you is to remove department Id from the employee table. Insert all records to the employees in Departments table.

Then it's a simple inner join.

And of course, never use select * in production code.

Comment: Thanks for the select * recommendation. The change in design has already been proposed but not yet approved. A bit of work may be required to convert current data.

Answer (score 4):

Here's my re-write of your query:

```
WITH summary AS (
   SELECT e.*
     FROM EMPLOYEES e
    WHERE e.isdeleted = @IsDeleted 
      AND e.parentid = 0)
SELECT a.*
  FROM summary a
 WHERE a.departmentid = @DepartmentId
UNION
SELECT b.*
  FROM summary b
  JOIN EMPLOYEESINDEPARTMENTS ed ON ed.employeeid = b.employeeid
                                AND ed.departmentid = @DepartmentId
```

The UNION is necessary to remove duplicates - if you know there'll never be duplicates, change `UNION` to `UNION ALL`.

The CTE called "summary" doesn't provide any performance benefit, it's just shorthand.

Comment: Thanks for the UNION recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you change the `IN` clause used in your query to `WHERE EXISTS`.

If you are using `IN` in your query it means you are not taking benifits of the indexes defined on the table, and the query will perform a complete table scan which impacts the query performance.

You can check this thread to convert a `IN` to `WHERE EXISTS`:

[Changing IN to EXISTS in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277632/changing-in-to-exists-in-sql)

Comment: -1 They are treated exactly the same in SQL Server http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/08/17/exists-vs-in/